# Unable to query JSON using Athena : HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Error: type expected at the position 0 of 'ARRAY <STRING>' but 'ARRAY' is found

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am getting the following error when I try to query JSON file using a glue table via Athena :

```
HIVE_METASTORE_ERROR: Error: type expected at the position 0 of 'ARRAY <STRING>' but 'ARRAY' is found. (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
This query ran against the "" database, unless qualified by the query.
```

The Glue table schema is as follows :

```
[
  {
    "Name": "id",
    "Type": "string",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "eligibleterritorycodes",
    "Type": "ARRAY <STRING>",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "excludedterritorycodes",
    "Type": "ARRAY <STRING>",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "isdeleted",
    "Type": "boolean",
    "Comment": ""
  },
  {
    "Name": "requestsuccessful",
    "Type": "boolean",
    "Comment": ""
  }
]
```

And the bucket to which this Glue table points just has one file with a single line :

```
{"id":"-1000000102013416","eligibleTerritoryCodes":["00"],"excludedTerritoryCodes":["US"],"isDeleted":false,"requestSuccessful":true}
```

I have also tried setting `ignore.malformed.json` as "true" for the glue table but to no success. I am not sure why it is giving such error when the glue table structure is exactly as the data in the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get past this error but the following Athena query helped me resolve the issue and unblock me:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE odp_table (
  dmid string,
  eligibleterritorycodes array<string>,
  excludedterritorycodes array<string>,
  isdeleted boolean,
  requestsuccessful boolean
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('ignore.malformed.json' = 'true')
 LOCATION 's3://odp-update-beta/final_request_models/"json_table" ';
 
 select * from json_table;
```

So instead of using Glue table, I have used created an  external table in athena with the same schema. This helpes me query the JSON file.